# C pointers: what's the difference between struc* A, struct *A and struct * A?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm doing some researches to better understand pointers in C, but I'm having a hard time understanding these:
Is 'struct* A' a pointer on a structure?
Then what is 'struct *A'?
And I've seen someone writing 'int const * a', what does this mean?

Comment: ``struct *A == struct* A``

Comment: `struct * A` (with any spacing) wouldn't compile, the struct tag is missing.

Answer (score 6):

> what's the difference between `struc* A`, `struct *A` and `struct * A`?

They're equivalent(ly wrong). C is a free-form language, whitespace doesn't matter.

> Is `struct* A` a pointer on a structure?

No, it's (still) a syntax error (`struct` is a reserved keyword). If you substitute a valid structure name in there, then it will be one, yes.

> `int const * a`, what does this mean?

This declares `a` to be a pointer to `const int`.

Comment: Whitespace does matter.  Consider `unsigned long Bridge;` vs `unsigned longBridge;`

Comment: @BenVoigt And also `"hello world"` is not the same as `"helloworld"`, sure.

Comment: @Pete: Yes, exactly.  It's the sequence of tokens that counts.

Answer (score 2):

`struct *A`, `struct* A` and `struct    *          A` are all the same thing and all eqaully wrong since you're missing the struct's name.

`int const *a` is a the same as `const int *a` and it means pointer to a const integer.

Aside: `int * const a` is different and it means const pointer and a non const integer.

Comment: There's nothing necessarily "constant" about a `const` qualified object.

Comment: @Carl: Yes there is.  But having a pointer-to-`const` does not imply that the object is `const` qualified.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I agree completely with your second statement, but `const` just means "you can't modify this", not that it's constant in any way.  It might very well change value.

Comment: @Carl: If it's applied to the object itself (meaning at the point of definition), then the value really and truly is immutable.  (attempting to modify a `const` object, for example by casting away `const`, results in undefined behavior)

Comment: I see what you're both saying so I've dropped the word constant to avoid confusion.

Comment: @BenVoigt, sure.  But the system is allowed to change the object's value outside the flow of control of your program.  One might declare a read-only memory mapped register `const` to catch bugs where someone tries to write to it for example.  Its value could still change to reflect underlying hardware state.

Comment: @Carl: That would still be a pointer-to-`const` (and `volatile`), meaning the program has a read-only view of the target.  Not a `const` object.

Comment: Maybe we're just arguing about semantics - a pointer-to-`const` *is* a pointer to a `const` object, right?

Comment: @Carl: Only sometimes.  Consider: `int a; const int* p = &a;`  `a`, the object, is not `const`.  `p`, which is a pointer-to-`const`, is a readonly view on an object which may or may not be constant (in this example it isn't).  But if you continue the example with `const int b; p = &b;`, now `b` is a `const` object, and there is nothing you can legally do to change it.

Comment: Aha - that makes sense, yup.

Answer (score 0):

They are all identical.

`struct *A` = `struct* A` = `struct*A` = `struct * A`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, `struct * A` et cetera are incorrect but identical.

However, a structure and a pointer can be created in the following manner:

```
/* Structure definition. */
struct Date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};

/* Declaring the structure of type Date named today. */
struct Date today;

/* Declaring a pointer to a Date structure (named procrastinate). */
struct Date * procrastinate;

/* The pointer 'procrastinate' now points to the structure 'today' */
procrastinate = &today;
```

Also, for your secondary question about the different ways in which pointers are declared, "What is `int const * a`?", here is an example that I adapted from **Programming in C, by Stephen G. Kochan**:

```
char my_char = 'X';

/* This pointer will always point to my_char. */
char * const constant_pointer_to_char = &my_char;
/* This pointer will never change the value of my_char.   */  
const char * pointer_to_a_constant_char = &my_char;
/* This pointer will always point to my_char and never change its value. */
const char * const constant_ptr_to_constant_char = &my_char;
```

When I first got started, I would find it helpful to read the definition from right to left, substituting the word 'read-only' for 'const'.  For example, in the last pointer I would simply say, "constant_ptr_to_constant_char is a read-only pointer to a char that is read-only".  In your question above for `int const * a` you can say, "'a' is a pointer to a read-only int".  Seems dumb, but it works.

There are some variations but when you run into them, you can find more examples by searching around this site.  Hope that helps!