# When should we use struct node* head=NULL and struct node *head=NULL?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have constructed a struct

```
struct node
{
int key;
struct node *left,*right;
}
```

`struct node *a;` means we constructed a pointer variable of the node, what does `struct node* a;` do? does it point to the variable a?

```
// C program to demonstrate insert operation in binary search tree
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int key;
    struct node *left, *right;
};

// A utility function to create a new BST node
struct node *newNode(int item)
{
    struct node *temp =  (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->key = item;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}

// A utility function to do inorder traversal of BST
void inorder(struct node *root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        inorder(root->left);
        printf("%d \n", root->key);
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}

/* A utility function to insert a new node with given key in BST */
struct node* insert(struct node* node, int key)
{
    /* If the tree is empty, return a new node */
    if (node == NULL) return newNode(key);

    /* Otherwise, recur down the tree */
    if (key < node->key)
        node->left  = insert(node->left, key);
    else if (key > node->key)
        node->right = insert(node->right, key);   

    /* return the (unchanged) node pointer */
    return node;
}

// Driver Program to test above functions
int main()
{
    /* Let us create following BST
              50
           /     \
          30      70
         /  \    /  \
       20   40  60   80 */
    struct node *root = NULL;
    root = insert(root, 50);
    insert(root, 30);
    insert(root, 20);
    insert(root, 40);
    insert(root, 70);
    insert(root, 60);
    insert(root, 80);

    // print inoder traversal of the BST
    inorder(root);

    return 0;
}
```

In this program we use the statement in functions like `struct node* insert(struct node* node, int key)`
when we perform operation, but while declaring a new node we used

```
struct node *newNode(int item)
```

When do we place * near to node, and what does this signify?

Comment: "`struct node *a;` means we constructed a structure variable of the node" No, it means we constructed a pointer vairable, not a structure variable.

Comment: "does it point to the variable a?" Yes, if the pointer to the variable `a` is assigned to it.

Comment: From the question title, `struct node* head=NULL` and `struct node *head=NULL` are the same. It is more usual to put the space before the `*` not after, then the usage is clearer, as in your `struct` members `struct node *left, *right;` which both reuquire a `*`. Even if you put the space *after* the first `*`, the `*right` member *still needs a star* as in `struct node* left, *right;`.

Comment: Also please note that the `*` when used in declarations/definitions of variables/functions is something different then the de-referencing operator `*`.

Comment: Isn't the real dupe here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15981068/694576?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spacing of the `*` doesn't matter.  `struct node * a` and `struct node* a` and `struct node *a` are all equivalent.

It always declares a pointer to a `struct node`.

However, you should be cautious of declaring multiple variables on the same line like that.  In particular, `struct node *a, b` declares `a` as a *pointer* and `b` as an *instance* of the struct. You've done it correctly, but it's a dangerous syntax that I usually prefer to avoid because it is error prone.